# How do I join these tables with active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have the following tables

```
Users
  - id
  - name

User_Skills
  - id
  - user_id
  - skill_id

Skills
  - id
  - name
```

I want to get all the users who have an exact set of skills

```
User.join(:user_skills).where('user_skills.skill_id IN (1,2,3)')
```

This returns all the users who have skills of either 1 OR 2 OR 3.

How do get the only the users with skills 1 AND 2 AND 3 ?

This does not work

```
 User.join(:user_skills).where('user_skills.skill_id = 1 and user_skills.skill_id = 2 and user_skills.skill_id = 3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def with_skills(*ids)
    ids.flatten!
    join(:user_skills).where(user_skills: {skill_id: ids}).group(users: id).having('COUNT(DISTINCT user_skills.id) = ?', ids.length)
  end
end
```

Comment: this should work if there are no duplicate entries i.e. a user has same skill more than once.

Comment: I assumed that's correct. Just to make it more general I'll add Distinct to count.